# Passing variable from shell script to mongo javascript fails

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

I have a code where I am running a mongo javascript using shell script command:

```
mongo --eval "var lower='30000';" <servername>:27017 < mongo.js;
```

But instead of running the mongo.js, it just connects to the server and breaks.
Logs:
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://:27017/test
MongoDB server version: 2.2.1
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match

This warning is not an issue, but it is not computing the mongo.js script. Can you tell what is wrong in my command?

I am calling this .js script from a shell script using the command written above is there some way I can pass multiple values to those variables?

Answer (score 0):

`--eval` makes mongo shell evaluate the specified javascript and ignore standard input.

Provide all of the code you wish to run either as `--eval` argument or in a file but don't use both together.

To pass variables to the shell script, create a new script:

```
echo "var lower='30000';" >run.js
cat mongo.js >>run.js
mongo <servername>:27017 < run.js;
```

Comment: So If I want to pass variables to the mongo.js script, how can I do that?

Comment: Define them in the script.

Comment: I am calling the mongo.js script from a shell script, to that shell script, the values are passed, they can vary also. Hence we cannot hardcode the values. So in such case what can I do?

Comment: Add these requirements to the question.

Comment: I have added, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: If we want to pass 3 variables to the same script, how can we do that?